# Embed Python interpreter in a Python application

Tags: python, interpreter, embedding

I'm looking for a way to ship the Python interpreter with my application (also written in Python), so that it doesn't need to have Python installed on the machine.

I searched Google and found a bunch of results about how to embed the Python interpreter in applications written in various languages, but nothing for applications written in Python itself... I don't need to "hide" my code or make a binary like `cx_freeze` does, I just don't want my users to have to install Python to use my app, that's all.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106725/how-to-bundle-a-python-application-including-dependencies-for-windows, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/an-executable-python-app, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950218/distributing-python-programs, etc.

Comment: finally yes, but at first i wasn't looking to freeze my app into a binary, even if it finally apeared to be the easiest solution to distribute my app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For distribution on Windows machines, look into [**py2exe**](http://www.py2exe.org/)

```
py2exe is a Python Distutils extension which converts Python scripts 
into executable Windows programs, able to run without requiring a 
Python installation
```

For the MacIntosh, there is [**py2app**](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html)   (but I'm not familiar with it)

And for both Windows and Linux, there's [**bbfreeze**](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bbfreeze/)  or also [**pyinstaller**](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)

Comment: Thanks, i'm realizing that despite the fact that i want to provide my source code with my app, the easiest way to do this (as Ignacio said) would still be to freeze my app into a binary and also ship the source code with it.

Comment: Yes, with this approach you have the best of both: a stand alone binary and the source code, which can be used within the interpreter, would the user wish to do this and/or would he/she decide to modify the program.

Answer (score 2):

You need *some* sort of executable in order to start Python. May as well be the one your app has been frozen into.

The alternative is to copy the executable, library, and pieces of the stdlib that you need into a private directory and invoke that against your app.

Answer (score 2):

Making a frozen binary using a utility like cx_freeze or py2exe is probably the easiest way to do this. That way you only need to distribute the executable. I know that you might prefer not to distribute a binary, but if that is a concern you could always give users the option to download the source and run from an interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows: [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/FrontPage)

For Linux: [Freeze](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze)

Full disclosure: I've only read about these, never used them. Perhaps some who has can comment?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.python-packager.com, it is a free webservice for building redistrutable python binaries based on pyinstaller. I've used it to build apps for Windows and it is very easy to use and also works with GUI apps.