# How can I distribute a Python program without requiring users to have a Python runtime?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am planning to create a Python program and distribute it bundled with C# GUI. How can I distribute the Python part of the program without requiring users to have Python?

Comment: what is your user's platform (OS) ?

Comment: This is a dup of at least a dozen questions, such as [How can I distribute python programs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558385/how-can-i-distribute-python-programs?rq=1), [Distributing Programs Written in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190635/distributing-programs-written-in-python), etc. (I think the latter has the best answers, albeit a bit out of date, but it's been marked as a dup of a less-useful one.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org) or a similar tool. Or bundle the Python runtime with your software. To do that, you can use [Pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org).

Comment: Or [py2app](http://pythonhosted.org/py2app/) if you're planning to distribute to Mac. Or both if you want to keep it portable.

Comment: [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) is a similar tool.

Comment: How can I easily bundle the runtime?

Answer (score 4):

In the past, I have used py2exe (windows) so that I do not have to ask them to install python.

py2exe creates an exe which the user clicks and it runs without a problem.

If you want to go beyond this, package it with something like innosetup and it adds an installer which is better.