# How to not give away source code with command line application in Python?

Tags: python

I have a Python program that uses the command line like below

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-I", "--example", help="Example: -I example")
```

When I go to run this I do

```
py .\name_of_file.py -I example
```

This is working fine, but the problem I have now is that 'name_of_file.py' calls functions in other files, imports other files, etc. This requires the user to have access to the source code, so this is obviously not a good solution. How can I still add the command line capability while putting the source code behind a wall or an executable or something along those lines?

Comment: You cannot obfuscate python

Comment: With Python, you can't.  That's the trade-off.  Python interprets your code at run-time, so your code has to be available.  Even if you "compile to exe", that's just wrapping your code into a zipfile that the interpreter can run later.'

Comment: You would have to distribute at least the`pyc` files containing the necessary byte code. An executable would just be a bundle containing a Python runtime and all the source code needed to run your application. In general, you can't distribute Python programs without distributing the source as well.

Comment: I mean, you can, but it affords you no protection from anything

Comment: Did you read any of these already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code-from-being-read-by-users, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558385/how-can-i-distribute-python-programs, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059509/create-a-single-executable-from-a-python-project, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527510/how-to-deploy-a-python-application-with-libraries-as-source-with-no-further-depe, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913367/how-can-i-distribute-a-python-program-without-requiring-users-to-have-a-python-r

Comment: Is your concern that the users can *see* the source code or that they *need* the source code?

Comment: Do you know [auto-py-to-exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/)?