# Bundling Python with mechanize and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, windows, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I have developed a tool in Python that I would be giving to an organization.

Suppose the organization is running Windows, and has none of **Python**, **mechanize** or **BeautifulSoup** module installed.

Now what is the best way to bundle/package my tool so that they could run it with the minimum overhead from their side?

As of now, I am asking them to do a lot of things.

Installation instructions:

Step 1. Download and install Python 2.7.3 from here

```
http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/python-2.7.3.msi
```

Step 2. Download and install easy_install from here

```
https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=57e1e64f6b7c7f1d2eddfc9746bbaf20
```

Step 3. Run the cmd prompt and run the following commands

```
easy_install mechanize
easy_install BeautifulSoup
```

Step 4. You are done.

Can the effort be minimized? How? I want it to be as easy as possible for them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this type of question has been asked [so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1950218/1072844) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/q/106725/1072844) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2933/1072844).

For your use case, you could use [**pyinstaller**](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). Here some example how to use it in your case:

Suppose your program is `spam.py` that contains following lines:

```
import mechanize
import BeautifulSoup

print "Hello World!"
```

After installing `pyinstaller` using `pip install pyinstaller`, execute the following command in the directory of your `spam.py` program.

```
pyinstaller spam.py
```

You'll get a bundled app for your program under the newly created `dist` folder. To create a single executable file for your app distribution, use `--onefile` option for the `pyinstaller` command. Now, you can copy the bundled file and give that to the organization.