# Distributing Python apps

Tags: python, cx-freeze, pyinstaller

Quick question... Once I build a .py app, with wx gui, etc... I can compile it with pyinstaller or cx_freeze, and send the binaries to my servers, correct?

Is this a good way to distribute a script?  I am fairly new to app development cycle...  I have a few python script which I would like to make public, because they make my life easier...

If you were to share some code with the rest of community, provide people the .py code, and wanted to distribute binaries as well, would you compile .py with pyinstaller and cx_freeze, or would you use some other method?

Dev environment currently is Mac OSX, and a debian domU....

Thanks!

Comment: Put the sources on Github or similar. If you actually think people who don't know how to run a Python script will want to use them, yes, you can "compile it with pyinstaller or cx_freeze, and send the binaries to my servers"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution depends on **who** you're releasing it to, and **what license** you're releasing it under.

If you're not concerned about revealing the code of the apps you're distributing, then a service like github or bitbucket is the way to go. The best way to contribute your code to a community (if you're releasing it open source) is through version control because it allows people to contribute and learn from it.

But, depending on your audience, you might need something more "user-friendly". In which case, **cx_freeze** and **pyinstaller** are perfectly acceptable solutions.

If you're distributing a **package**, you may want to look into [setuptools](http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html)

Answer (score 0):

See also http://wiki.python.org/moin/DistributionUtilities and [How can I distribute Python programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558385/how-can-i-distribute-python-programs)

To share open source projects online, [GitHub](https://github.com/) is the popular choice.