# Deploying C++ program with python embedded

Tags: python, c++, windows, qt

I have a Qt  C++ project in which, for some functionality,I have added Python. The C++ function calls python script and returns the values.Like the below Example.

```
PyObject *pName,*pModule,*pFunc;
PyObject *pArgs,*pValue;
const char *module="getBeamData";
pName=PyUnicode_FromString(module);
pModule=PyImport_Import(pName);
if(pModule!=NULL){
    pFunc=PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule,"getBeamDose");
    if(pFunc&&PyCallable_Check(pFunc)){
        pArgs=PyTuple_New(2);        
  PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs,0,PyBytes_FromString(path.toStdString().c_str()));
        PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs,1,PyLong_FromLong(fraction));      
        pValue=PyObject_CallObject(pFunc,pArgs);
```

It calls the  script getBeamdata.py. Functionality works fine. Do I have to install python and libraries(like numpy) for all customer and ship script ? Or is there any other way without sending script.

Answer (score 1):

Without statically compiling your Python script you will need to distribute:

- requirements.txt (for all libraries/modules required by your script).
- details on the correct version of Python required by the script (2.7/3 etc).

Alternatively you could look into creating an executable using [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) and distribute that instead, although you'll need to modify the way your program interacts with the Python script.

Some further details on distributing Python [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558385/how-can-i-distribute-python-programs).

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd do it with some sort of installer.

Now in that installer, you can of course embed the [`wheel`](https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) version of your script, which is in addition going to be installed using [`setuptools`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

In that setuptools script you can mention dependencies, but that means that your client should have either Python installed on his/her computer, or you should ship your own version of Python embedded with the software.

Such functionality can be also be achieved using [`Boost.Python`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/index.html)