# How to make a python application distributable

Tags: python-3.x, project, software-distribution

My question pertains to distributing a python application the proper way. i have done research, but the answers appear to be vague and usually instruct the user to upload projects to the python package index. I simply want to make sure i research the proper methods instead of steering in the wrong direction.

I have been writing a stock analysis application with stored text files, and a dozen or so python scripts that interact with each other. Outside computers are to communicate with my servers through a random port (not the internet ports). all the imports work properly and the communication works properly, but i have no clue how to approach the distribution/setup or the GUI.

1. As an application with dozens of python scripts, should i write each script as an executable via pyInstaller, or should i add a python environment to the application to install python on all the user systems?
2. I need to add 'README', and 'LICENSE' to the application. What is the point of set up? is that a resource so python knows what is going on or does it actually setup the application? Does it need a URL, and what is the point of using the URL? Do i need anything else for the setup tools?
3. How do i package the entire application to download on user systems? I want the software to be uploaded via a URL link or from a USB. Do i have to make a tar file? i can do it automatically by writing my own python setup script, but i believe python has an easier way. Do i put a function in the setup to send an executable file to the desktop as a controller so the users don't open all the folders? How do i install from a link on  a website?
4. For a graphical interface for the users on python applications, do most programmers use tkinter, or python integration into HTML, CSS? I do not want this application to be live in a website, but rather as a desktop application. Do i need to use a framework, such as django, to implement python into my html code?

I apologize if this is all unorganized. Ive always coded my own programs and never distributed or put a GUI on any of the scripts, so i just want to make sure i approach the task the right way.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558385/how-can-i-distribute-python-programs 
And edit/split your question for the 4th sub-question; it is unrelated to the distribution.