# Produce an python executable from a pipenv directory

Tags: python, pipenv

I've just built a selenium test case in a python3 pipenv environment that is compatible with the nagios reporting format. It works fine as my user, but I'm not sure how best to get to work as a nagiosadmin user, as this user has no home directory for the pipenv files to go into. I'd also prefer not to have to install the libraries in the system space.

Ideally, I'd like to cd to my pipenv and type something like

```
makeinstaller
```

which would create a directory structure containing my python file(nagioselenium.py) and the necessary libraries. I'd then move this, change permissions and run with something like;

```
python3 nagiosselenium/nagiosselenium.py
```

Is there a simple way to do this, or is my only option to install the libraries system-wide?

Thanks

Comment: Hm. Recurring question. Most ancient on SO is from 2013: [How can I distribute python programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558385/how-can-i-distribute-python-programs).  Have you tried [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable)?