# Pillow working in python 3.10.x but not in 3.11

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am using the pillow library for images in python. With python 3.10.x I dont get an error when I import Image from PIL

`from PIL import Image`

However if I run the same code in python 3.11.x, I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\einfa\Downloads\Displaying-Images-With-Turtle_ORIGINAL\main\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from libs.PIL import Image
  File "C:\Users\einfa\Downloads\Displaying-Images-With-Turtle_ORIGINAL\main\libs\PIL\Image.py", line 100, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'libs.PIL' (C:\Users\einfa\Downloads\Displaying-Images-With-Turtle_ORIGINAL\main\libs\PIL\__init__.py)
```

Does somebody know a solution so I can run my program with PIL in both versions?

I tried installing different pillow versiosn at first which did't work. After that I installed python 3.11.x and python 3.10.x and noticed this difference. I installed pillow via pip with the command pip3 install pillow

Comment: I installed pillow in the working directory so I can send my project to other people without them must having pillow installed

Comment: installing a binary Python package, like Pillow, depends on the version of Python you're using.  hence what you're doing is always going to fail.  you could look at bundling everything up into an "installer" binary.  maybe have a look https://stackoverflow.com/q/1558385/1358308 for other ideas

Comment: Which version of PIL do you have installed?

Comment: @MatteoZanoni the most recent version of PIL

Comment: Can you be more specific? `print(libs.PIL.__version__)`

Comment: @HelpersCoockiesss have a look here at all the different binaries available: https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/#files it's not going to work!

Comment: @MatteoZanoni 9.3.0

Comment: If you install pillow using pip (not by cloning the project in your source code) and then run `from PIL import Image` does it work?

Comment: @MatteoZanoni in python 3.10.x it still works, however if I run then in python 3.11.x, it says "No module named 'PIL'"

Comment: Probably you have not installed pillow in your python3.11 environment

Comment: @MatteoZanoni but when I load pillow from the working directory, I get an error nevertheless

Comment: Package your code correctly, and this is not a problem. `pip install yourapp` will install not just your application, but whatever dependencies your application specifies. This is not limited to `pip`; you can use `poetry` or some other packaging tool to accomplish the same thing. I would start with https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/